# ubuntu-desktop do not install on Oracle VM (LTS 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, desktop-environments, arm

I'm trying to install ubuntu-desktop on an arm enviroment at an Oracle VM (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1013-oracle aarch64).

My /etc/apt/sources.list is as bellow:

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
**deb http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy main restricted**
# deb-src http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
**deb http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates main restricted**
# deb-src http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
**deb http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy universe**
# deb-src http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy universe
**deb http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates universe**
# deb-src http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
**deb http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy multiverse**
# deb-src http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy multiverse
**deb http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates multiverse**
# deb-src http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
**deb http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse**
# deb-src http://sa-saopaulo-1-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

**deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted**
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted
**deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe**
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe
**deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse**
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse

## From here I added by myself (user added)
**deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy main restricted universe multiverse**
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy main restricted universe multiverse
**deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse**
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
**deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse**
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
**deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy partner**
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy partner
```

When I try to install ubuntu-dektop I'm having dependencies issues that I'm not getting a way to handle. This is the output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-tgm-instance:~$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk : Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (= 1:22.04.10) but 1:22.04.11 is to be installed
                               Depends: python3-distupgrade (= 1:22.04.10) but 1:22.04.11 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know if it is anything related to ARM's architecture but I tried lots of things without success. But I'm not an expert so I'm sharing with you hoping any of you can have a better idea about what can be done. I don't know if this is relevant, but this server was created yesterday on Ubuntu 22.04 already.

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update` lately?   It looks more like you have outdated repository information.

Comment: Yes, I did. It did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, but on an AMD-based Oracle Ubuntu instance, so don't think it's an ARM specific problem. Got around it for now by using Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal) vs Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy).  It's obviously not ideal, so I'd be interested in how you eventually solve the problem.

Comment: I did the same. I gave up 22.04. Let's wait and see if we can get a solution in a near future.

Comment: Problem seems fixed now - think Oracles mirror is being patched differently than regular Ubuntu one.